# Installing Fedora 28 next to Windows 10 (another harddisk)

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

In my laptop I have two SSD. The First one is used by the Windows 10 (SDA device), on the second I have installed the Fedora 28 (SDB device)

But I have a big problem (Yes, I have checked some tutorial but those are about how to install fedora and windows next to each other on the same harddisk! and not separated harddisk)

Bios - FastBoot disabled (UEFI used)
Windows 10 - I disabled the Fast-Startup funcion (In Control Panel/System/.../Power buttons)

Partition looks like in Fedor installer:

- sda1 boot efi of windows
- sda2 boot of windows
- sda3 Root of windows
- sdb1 boot efi of Fedora
- sdb2 boot of Fedora
- sdb3 Root of Fedora (yeap no swap for 32GBram, and now home directory)

So I have installed Fedora on the SDB, but after boot the Grub does not list the Windows 10... 
I have tried to fix with `os-probe`, no success, or with `grub2-mkconfig` reran command but still no success, it seems to me these programs cannot see the sda device.

Then I tried something, I changed the boot order! And something interesting about the Fedora, it is very agressive.
1. Windows 10 SSD
2. Fedora USB Live
3. Fedora 28 SSD.
This is the order and what happened? Fedora 28 SSD was boot in Efi (Legacy mode deactivated) I could not boot the usb live neither the windows 10.

The only way to boot the Windows 10 SSD or Fedora USB live is that I am going to deactivate the Fedora 28 SSD.

Do you have any idea how can update the windows 10 or Fedora 28 boot loader (Grub) to be able to boot both OS?

Laptop is HP Studio Zbook G3 workstation

Comment: You sure that both Fedora and Windows are installed in UEFI mode? This is why I'm asking: https://askubuntu.com/questions/910345/os-prober-does-not-return-windows-10-on-another-drive

Comment: you can check with `efibootmgr -v`